# Illegal access to loading collection (hibernate.LazyInitializationException)

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate persistence provider.

I have one to many mapping, I used

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mSearchPreference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

I can see the one to many SQL statements on the console, eventhough i am getting the exception

```
illegal access to loading collection  (hibernate.LazyInitializationException)
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readElementExistence(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:187)
```

Can someone help me out what other arrangements I need to do?

Comment: are you sure it is not another collection that you are adding to? You should have more stacktrace available.

Comment: hi here is the full stack trace

Comment: @SatishKumar Can you show the code that you are using to fetch the entity?

Answer (score 0):

This normally means that Hibernate session has already been closed when trying to access new entities. Two options to solve this issue are:

- Review ALL your model graph and set the appropiate EAGER fetch type when needed.
- Set an extended persistent content: @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)

Comment: I am using Set for the one to many relationship is that any problem, do i need to configure any extra thing to use Set, what is the actual difference of using Set and List in Hibernate maping.